# When updating my orderer with the MSPanchor files I get an error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

The following is the command called and the output.
This is during setting up channels on a hyperledger fabric network.

```
peer channel update -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx
```

> 2018-03-22 03:19:34.849 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
>   2018-03-22 03:19:34.849 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
>   2018-03-22 03:19:34.850 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 003 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
>   Error: Invalid channel create transaction : mismatched channel ID channel != mychannel
>   `

Has anyone encountered this?

Answer (score 1):

> Endorser and orderer connections initialized Error: Invalid channel create transaction : mismatched channel ID channel != mychannel

You are trying to apply configuration transaction which aimed for channel with id `channel`, for channel id `mychannel`.

You either need to regenerate config transaction for `mychannel` or to use existing one for `channel`, e.g.:

```
peer channel update -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c channel -f ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx
```

Answer (score 1):

A situation when this error usually occurs is when an Org is part of 2 different channels but only 1 MSPAnchors.tx file has been created from configtxgen tool for a given profile. Ideally, you would want to generate MSPAnchors.tx file for each channel which that Org will be part of.

Assume you are planning to keep Org1 as part of 2 different channels (Ch1 and Ch2), then you will have to generate .tx file for each of these channels:

```
configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors1.tx -channelID Ch1 -asOrg Org1MSP
configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors2.tx -channelID Ch2 -asOrg Org1MSP
```

This will create two .tx files in Channel-Artifacts folder:

```
Org1MSPanchors1.tx
Org1MSPanchors2.tx
```

Then for updating anchor peers on Ch1:

```
peer channel update -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c ch1 -f ./channel-artifacts/ORG1MSPanchors1.tx
```

And on Ch2:

```
peer channel update -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c ch2 -f ./channel-artifacts/ORG1MSPanchors2.tx
```

The above channel update command is assuming that `CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED` is set to false otherwise you'll have to provide CA file path of Orderer using `--cafile` flag

Answer (score 0):

Try run `peer channel list` maybe channel with such name doesn't exist.